# Play sound on built-in speaker with phonegap? (simulate phonecall)

Tags: cordova

is there a way to play a sound with buil-in speaker with phonegap?

i mean, for example, to simulate a telephone call

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To play sound you could simply use the audio tag of HTML5. Nothing PhoneGap specific needed here. But PhoneGap has an API for that http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media

Comment: Yes, i know...but it will reproduce the sound with external speakers (i mean speakers beside the plugin for charge the battery).

i would like to play with same speaker that use the telephone for calls.

Comment: @RiccardoNeri hello bro, have you found the way to use speaker for telephone calls instead of external media speakers? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cordova plugin [AudioToggle](http://github.com/alongubkin/audiotoggle):

Install:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/danielflippance/audiotoggle.git --save
```

Then in your javascript code:

```
AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.EARPIECE);
```

After that all sound should be outpuded to the phone interneal speaker.

Comment: That plugin doesnt work. Repo returns 404 error and lots of unanswered issues have been opened.

Comment: There is a fork of this repo which works seamlessly 
https://github.com/danielflippance/audiotoggle